# When I try to reload .bash_profile from the command line I have some problems

Tags: shell, bash

How can I reload .bash_profile from the command line? when I try this command on the terminal by typing `su - username`  or `source ~/.bash_profile` I got this:

when I try with `su - username` :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Khayati-iteb:~ Khayati_iteb$ su - khayati_iteb
Password:
-bash: /Users/macbookpro/.profile: No such file or directory
```

when I try with `source ~/.bash_profile` :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Khayati-iteb:~ Khayati_iteb$ source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /Users/macbookpro/.profile: No such file or directory
MacBook-Pro-de-Khayati-iteb:~ Khayati_iteb$
```

Comment: You appear to have a line like `source /Users/macbookpro/.profile` in your `.bash_profile`, and that path does not exist.

Comment: How about posting your `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 0):

After accessing to `.bash_profile` with the command `nano ~/.bash_profile` the first line was : 
`source ~/.profile` so I changed this to `source ~/.bash_profile` 
and the problem is resolved. Thank you very much guys  `chepner` `SiKing`

Comment: Why should it source itself?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your question ?

Comment: You said you are doing `source ~/.bash_profile` inside `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: No I mean that inside the ‘~/.bash_profile‘ I changed the first line from ‘source ~/.profile‘ to ‘source ~/.bash_profile‘